# Error while trying to create code to send JSON to GCP using Service Account Credentials

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

Error while trying to send content to Google Cloud using Service Account Credentials

We have a bucket create for our projects purposes.

I have created a java service which tries to send a JSON content to bucket.

I am using the build in libraries to send the content to the bucket.

I have attached the JARS used as mentioned by the documentation and a simple 4 line code to send the file content to the bucket.

I pretty much followed the below GITHUB link as advised by the documentation.

But i am not sure if i have the latest versions of the jars required,while the documentation mentions only a handful or jars such as(google-auth-library-oauth2-http,google-cloud-core,google-cloud-storage and google-auth-library-credentials) i have had to add a whole lot of others jars to resolve dependency errors for the above jars.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-java

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/auth/samples/AuthExample.java

```
Here is my code

    import com.google.auth.Credentials;
    import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
    import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

            Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath));
                Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

            BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("tms-data", "test");  
                BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
                Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(("UTF-8")));

I have imported the following jars 

List of Jars used 

commons-logging-1.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
google-api-client-jackson2-1.25.0.jar
google-http-client-1.25.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
httpclient-4.5.5.jar
jsr305-3.0.2.jar
google-oauth-client-1.25.0.jar
gson-2.1.jar
threetenbp-1.3.3.jar
gax-grpc-1.34.0.jar
gax-1.34.0.jar
google-auth-library-credentials-0.9.0.jar
google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar
google-cloud-storage-1.51.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.26.0.jar
guava-23.0.jar
api-common-1.2.0.jar
google-cloud-core-grpc-1.52.0.jar
google-cloud-core-1.52.0.jar
google-cloud-core-http-1.52.0.jar
google-api-client-1.26.0.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar

But i am still getting the following error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions.<init>(HttpTransportOptions.java:131)
at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions.<init>(HttpTransportOptions.java:45)
at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$Builder.build(HttpTransportOptions.java:90)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.getDefaultHttpTransportOptions(StorageOptions.java:106)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$StorageDefaults.getDefaultTransportOptions(StorageOptions.java:101)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:288)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.<init>(StorageOptions.java:83)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.<init>(StorageOptions.java:31)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$Builder.build(StorageOptions.java:78)
at WtrTMSTripAdvisor.v1.priv.service.sendJSONToGCP(service.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.JavaService.baseInvoke(JavaService.java:407)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.process(InvokeManager.java:650)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.util.tspace.ReservationProcessor.process(ReservationProcessor.java:39)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.StatisticsProcessor.process(StatisticsProcessor.java:49)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ServiceCompletionImpl.process(ServiceCompletionImpl.java:243)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ValidateProcessor.process(ValidateProcessor.java:49)
at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.PipelineProcessor.process...<truncated>
```

Comment: Do you use a dependency management tool (maven, gradle)? If not, you should consider using one. Maybe a transitive dependency is missing. (i.e. a jar that you do not depend on directly, but used by some jar you directly use)

Comment: ah thanks David unforunately not at the moment,we dont develop a lot on Java.I am webMethods developer(A product of Software AG Suite) and we use Java for very few things.Yes there were loads of transitive dependency ,actually even now i know the Jar the error is referring to its called (google-api-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar),but this seems to be beta and i cant find any official release for this jar

Comment: Actually, it is pretty easy to convert it to a minimal maven project. You will save lots of time (like searching for what's missing) even in a little project. Or if you do not want to, you can create a single `pom.xml` somewhere with necessary dependencies, and run a `mvn dependency:tree`, this will list the transitive dependencies, and you can download them manually (or copy them from your local maven repo).

Comment: The beta seems to be the recent release (at least only this is listed here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-extensions). Maybe it is not used in newer versions of the project.

Comment: okay thanks David i shall try the Minimal Maven project you are suggesting tomorrow,as you can see there are multiple versions of the same Jar and certain jars versions may only be compatible with certain version of other jars,hope the Maven project will take care of this dependency.Also the actual URL to connect to the cloud seems to be hidden inside the Jars,i am hoping that a future release of a jar will not break my code.